# Proper way to store ordered set of strings in database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

First of all, I have xml file I need to save in mysql database. I have child elements that can occur from one to unbounded times. Are there any constraints I can use in sqlalchemy ORM or I have to save order from application?

The table should look like:

```
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  id  |    name   |  part | parent_id |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 1    | foo       |   1   |    123    |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 2    | bar       |   2   |    123    |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 3    | baz       |   1   |    345    |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

In other words, what is a proper way to add explicit ordering to many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Any ordering needs to be done in code. Once inserted in a table and selected from that table the order is not guaranteed. So also on retrieval you will have to apply an order, in that part adding `ORDER BY` in SQL is the handiest way to go.